# In R: How can I compute the EWMA of a time series

Tags: r, time-series

Suppose I have a xts object in R; a time series consisting of, lets say, 1000 months.
I want to calculate a EWMA series based on this time series in such a way that in total 50% of the weight is put in the first three months. I am not aware of any fast/efficient method to do this in R.